# Vue index.html contains <link> tags to several lazy-loaded components

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to improve the load time of my website, and towards that, I'm using the following settings in my `vue.config.js`:

```
config.output.chunkFilename(`js/[name].[chunkhash:8].js`)

config.optimization
  .runtimeChunk('single')
  .splitChunks({
    chunks: 'all',
    maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
    minSize: 0,
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name (module) {
        // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
        // or node_modules/packageName
          const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1]

          // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
          return `npm.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Additionally, I also load all my routes dynamically:
**router.js**

```
const LandingPage = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "view-landing-page" */ '@C/landing-page')
const HomePage = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "view-home-page" */ '@C/home-page')
const Room = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "view-room" */ '@C/room')

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'landingPage',
      component: LandingPage
    },
    {
      path: '/land',
      name: 'landingPage',
      component: LandingPage
    },
    {
      path: '/home',
      name: 'homePage',
      component: HomePage
    },
    {
      path: '/*',
      name: 'roomPage',
      component: Room
    }
  ]
})
```

Each of these views *also* use lazy-loaded components. For example:
**room.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'room',
  mixins: [SocketEventsMixin],
  components: {
    'video-element': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "video-element" */ '@RC/media/video-element'),
    'video-chat': () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "video-chat" */ '@RC/communications/video-chat'),
  }
}
```

However, even with all this, I see the following in my `index.html`:

```
...
<link href=/css/view-room.1ce954c7.css rel=prefetch>
<link href=/js/view-room.fe2de329.js rel=prefetch>
...
<link href=/css/video-element.8342e42f.css rel=prefetch>
<link href=/js/video-element.ab0e6cca.js rel=prefetch>
...
```

As a result, a whopping 4.5MB is downloaded on visiting the landing page, which does not require *any* of these assets.

How do I ensure that `index.html` only contains the bare-minimum scripts/CSS, and have everything else be loaded dynamically? What causes an asset to be included in `index.html` as opposed to being dynamically loaded? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see `@C/landing-page`, which sounds weird to me. Is `@` an alias to `/src`? Then you might want to define the path as `@/C/landing-page`.

Comment: Those are my (custom) aliases. The site itself loads all content, so I suspect the aliases are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Vue-CLI automatically sets `webpackPrefetch: true` for all lazy-loaded components. I do not know how you can conditionally turn it on/off so in my projects I am turning it off completely:

```js
// vue.config.js
  chainWebpack: config =>
  {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch'); // for async routes
    config.plugins.delete('preload'); // for CSS
  }
```

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try this out and report back in a bit. I believe you _can_ turn off conditionally with `/* webpackPrefetch: false */` (https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments)

Comment: I have some doubts - I think that the allowed values are either `true` or `string`. To have a `false` you should actually remove the magic comment.