# Webpack loads all chunks on page ready

Tags: javascript, webpack, lazy-loading, code-signing

Webpack builds chunks correctly, code splitting works.

But when page has loaded it started to load all chunks for the whole project.

It's crazy cause code is simple

```
const APP_ROUTES = {
    '/blog/:article': import('../pages/blog/_article.sexy'),
    '/blog/': import('../pages/blog/index.sexy'),
    '/home': import('../pages/home.sexy'),
    '/': import('../pages/index.sexy')
};
```

And nothing more..

Hope anyone knows how to solve that. Appreciate any help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411136/5962802

Comment: @IVOGELOV It's not Vue, there is no prefetch, webpack generates Promise.all instead import() in bundle

Comment: Well, I could be wrong but I think that the proper syntax is to use arrow functions `"/": () => import("../pages/index.sexy")` Have you tried that ?