# Vue takes more than 5 minutes to load the first time after build

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Every time a build is completed and i refresh the page it takes more than 5 minutes for the page to finish loading.

I've looked through the the browser network log and i noticed that vue is loading every component and trying to cache them even though i used dynamic imports for code splitting.

After the first reload it starts loading the page faster. Is there a way i can prevent the initial reload from trying to get all the components or is there another way to optimise the build after dynamic imports.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62411136/5962802

Comment: 5 minutes? Do you have a reproduction?